# What simple tools exist for locally intercepting web requests and serving up pages?

Tags: proxy, httprequest

During web development certain resources that web requests are made to may not exist locally, but will in a production setting. What tools exist that allow you to specify such resources and the results they should respond with?

I am running on Mac OSX so I'm imaging there must be some type of *nix program that implements a simple web proxy server that allows you to do this.

Comment: Specifically an AWS EC2 instance data resource. For example, a GET request from any EC2 instance to http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname will return its public hostname. In a local development environment (i.e. not on EC2), this resource does exist, so I'm interested in a mechanism (tool) to intercept such requests and respond with something appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your development platform, it may be possible to set up a dev environment flag (I'm thinking Rails here but it's applicable to anything) and a production environment flag. Then you define like so:

```
if prod_environment
  HOSTNAME = get("169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname")
else
  HOSTNAME=something_fake
```